# Git Status hangs using Cygwin

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

On my Windows machine, I have a repository that works nicely with msysgit. But when I try running `git status` on cygwin, it just hangs, without printing anything until I press Ctrl-C.

How can I investigate this to find out the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: which git ? Cygwin one ? In which terminal ?

Comment: @matzeri what is your question referring to? Have you read my question?

Comment: I read it. But it is not clear to me if you are referring to msysgit run inside cygwin terminal(mintty) , or cygwin git run on windows console or cygwin git run on mintty.

Comment: msysgut run inside git bash, and git run on standard cygwin installation

Comment: same issue here, did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this was the difference in [`core.autocrlf`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#__code_core_autocrlf_code) setting. When install git for windows, I set it to automatically convert line endings in both directions, so the files in the filesystem were actually different from the files saved in git history - but windows git always hid these differences.

Meanwhile, cygwin git was working extremely slow because it detected differences in every line of thousands of text files in my repository.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: You change the setting not to change the line endings.