# Git Status hangs in cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

Here a question was [asked about the same issue with a very limited answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308455/git-status-hangs-using-cygwin) (I would have commented on the question, but my account doesn't have enough points :P)

I am working with two terminals. The default terminal from "Git Bash" installed via the windows install from git-scm.com, and I am also running cygwin (mintty.exe for clarity). I'm the only team member not using SourceTree for git and have to write my scripts so they work in cygwin - not just Git Bash.

The linked question details that their - like my own - cygwin hangs while trying to call `git status`. They alluded to discovering the source of the problem but didn't clarify the solution to the issue.

I tried checking the `core.autocrlf` fields in both terminals and they matched - which I thought the original question was meaning for the answer to be. Anyone able to provide a little guidance on how to stop git on cygwin from hanging on `git status`?

Comment: If you clone a repository and you use only cygwin git, does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The first test needs to be the `PATH` and `HOME` variable: make sure to launch your Cygwin session form a CMD with the minimal PATH possible.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Cygwin
# or
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\bin
```

Once in your cygwin shell, check your .bashrc in order, again, to set the minimal PATH possible, making sure there is no interference.
Then try again.